# What is the name of the king whose brother has been raised as a girl?

Tags: monarchy

I remember reading about a prince (probably French) who has been raised as a girl to avoid him fighting against his brother for the throne, a few years ago. To be honest, the story seems intriguing and I'd like to know more about it but I can't bring myself to remember any name.

Answer (score 6):

Are you thinking of [Philippe I, Duke of Orléans, brother of Louis XIV?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_I,_Duke_of_Orl%C3%A9ans#Marriages_and_love_life)